# Why is scanf() not taking my second input?

Tags: c, scanf

Why is **scanf()** not taking input for the second time as we can clearly see from the screenshot it is using the same value provided to it for the first input?

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct NODE{
int data;
struct NODE *link;
};
struct NODE *head = NULL;
int currentSize = 0;

void print(){
struct NODE *ptr = head;

//Printing the whole linked list;
while(ptr){
    printf("%d", ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->link;
    }
}

void insert(int value){

//if this is the first element in the linked list
if(head == NULL){      
    head = (struct NODE *)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
    head->data = value;
    currentSize = 1;
    return;
}

//if we traverse the linked list to the last element and then we the element
struct NODE *ptr = head; 

//traversing
while(ptr->link != NULL)
ptr = ptr->link;

//new node creation and adding it to the linked list
struct NODE *new = (struct NODE *)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
currentSize += 1;
new->data = value;
new->link = ptr->link;
ptr->link = new;
}

int main(){
printf("Options:\n1. Insert a node\n4. Print the Linked List\n5. Enter 0 to exit\n");
printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
int choice = scanf(" %d", &choice);
printf("Value of Choice %d\n", choice);
while(choice != 0){
    if(choice == 1){
        printf("Enter the Value: ");
        int value = scanf("%d", &value);            
        insert(value);
    }
    else if(choice == 4)
        print();
    else
        printf("Wrong Input");

    printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
    choice = scanf(" %d", &choice);
    printf("Value of Choice %d\n", choice);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have a space before the integer %d identifier within the quotes of your scanf

Comment: choice = scanf("%d", &choice); try without the space

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int value = scanf("%d", &value);`

scanf returns the number of items successfully read. Since you're reading 1 item and it is successful that is then written into the value variable, overwriting the 4 that scanf wrote into it before returning.
So to be clear, it is reading the 2nd input, but the input you recorded is immediately overwritten.

Comment: please take a look at my another screenshot that i uploaded.

Comment: @Satvik_08 Either create a separate variable that will hold the return value of scanf or don't store the return value. so either `int ret_val = scanf("%d", &value)` or `scanf("%d", &value);` same goes for the line that gets the choice. What you are currently doing is overwriting your choice and value with the scanf's return which in this case is 1 (but could be 0 or EOF).